# Directional derivative and Jacobian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian, frechet-derivative

I have a problem with an exercise that goes as follows:

> Let $\mathbf{f}$ be a $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ function and
>    $\mathbf{a}$ an interior point of the domain of $\mathbf{f}$. Let
>    $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\mathbf{v}\| = 1$. The
>    directional derivative of $\mathbf{f}$ in $\mathbf{a}$ in the
>    direction of $\mathbf{v}$ is given by    $$ \frac{\partial
>  \mathbf{f}}{\partial \mathbf{v}}(\mathbf{a}) := \lim_{t\to0,
>  t\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t
>  \mathbf{v})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t} \in \mathbb{R}^m. $$  Show that
>    if $\mathbf{f}$ is differentiable in $\mathbf{a}$, then the
>    directional derivate exists and is equal to
>    $D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\cdot\mathbf{v}$, with
>    $D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$ defined by:     $$ D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}) =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}{\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial
>  x_{1}}(\mathbf{a})} & {\cdots} & {\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial
>  x_{n}}(\mathbf{a})} \\ {\vdots} & {\ddots} & {\vdots} \\
>  {\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}}(\mathbf{a})} & {\dots} &
>  {\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}(\mathbf{a})}\end{array}\right). $$

Could anyone help me with this proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then,$$\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\bigl\lVert f(a+w)-f(a)-Df(a)(w)\bigr\rVert}{\lVert w\rVert}=0.\tag1$$So, consider the vectors $w$ of the form $tv$, with $t\in\mathbb R$. You deduce then from $(1)$ that$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\bigl\lVert f(a+tv)-f(a)-Df(a)(tv)\bigr\rVert}{\lVert tv\rVert}=0.\tag2$$Clearly, $(2)$ is equivalent to$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)-tDf(a)(v)}t=0.$$In other words,$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}t=Df(a)(v).\tag3$$But the LHS of $(3)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $v$. And, since$$\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}(a)} & {\cdots} & {\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}}(a)} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ {\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}}(a)} & \cdots & {\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}(a)}\end{bmatrix}$$is the matrix of $Df(a)$ with respect to the canonical basis, the RHS of $(3)$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}(a)} & {\cdots} & {\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{n}}(a)} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ {\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{1}}(a)} & \cdots & {\frac{\partial f_{m}}{\partial x_{n}}(a)}\end{bmatrix}.v.$$

Answer (score -1):

This question, as is presented, is **not possible** to answer since you are being asked to prove something which is logically inconsistent - not very fair tbh.

The impossibility lies in the fact that there is no expression for $\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\cdot\mathbf{v}$ - because there is no such thing as a dot product between a matrix and a vector. Furthermore, a dot product yields a *scalar value*, yet the directional derivative **must** be *vector-valued* in this instance (since $\mathbf{f}$ itself is given as being vector-valued, and the directional derivative is explicitly given to be a member of $\mathbb{R}^m$ by the definition from the question).

But we ***can*** **easily show** that the directional derivative is equal to $\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{v}$ - ie the matrix product of the Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})$ (aka Derivative matrix) and the vector $\mathbf{v}$, as follows...

1. Firstly note that by setting $ \mathbf{c}(t)=\mathbf{a}+t
    \mathbf{v}$ the question-given definition for the directional derivative can be re-expressed:
   $$
   \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{v})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t}
   \equiv \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(t))-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(0))}{t} \tag{1} 
   $$
2. Now, we define $\mathbf{g}(t)=f(\mathbf{c}(t))$. Observe that we know $\mathbf{g}'(t)$ exists, by the Chain Rule, since it is the derivative of the composition of $\mathbf{f}$ (given as differentiable by the question) and $\mathbf{c}$ (also differentiable), and we proceed to evaluate this derivative at $t=0$:

$$
\mathbf{g}'(0)= 
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\mathbf{g}(0+h)-\mathbf{g}(0)}{h}\\=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(h))-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(0))}{h} \equiv \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(t))-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(0))}{t}  \tag{2}
$$
...where the final line follows from the fact that changing the limiting variable from $h$ to $t$ is irrelevant in determining value of the limit.

3. By comparison of $(1)$ with $(2)$ we can see:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \lim_{t\to0} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{v})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t}
   =\mathbf{g}'(0)
   &=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(t)) \\
   &=\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c}(0))\mathbf{D}\mathbf{c}(0) &&\textit{ (Directly by the chain rule)}\\
   &=\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{c}'(0) \\
   &=\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{v} &&\textit{ ($\mathbf{c}'(0)=\mathbf{v}$)}\\
   \\&\therefore \underline{\underline{=\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\mathbf{v}}(a) \equiv\mathbf{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{v}}}
   \end{align}
   $$